# Bootstrap 3 modal does not close on outside click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created a modal using call,

```
 $('#myModalContent').modal('show');
```

html is:

```
<div class=" modal fade" id="myModalContent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is when i click outside the modal popup, its doesn't close. (its closes on esc)

Comment: Which version of bootstrap do you use? It doesn't work with bootstrap 2.1, but works with v2.3 and v3 : http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/372/

Comment: Have you tried adding `data-backdrop="true"` to your `class='modal'` div? True is the default behavior that allows for background click dismissal and `data-backdrop="static"` is the behaviour that your explaining, no dismissal

Comment: It is not related to angularjs so you can remove the angularjs tag

Comment: @Getz, I am using 3.1.1.....

Comment: @Siddesh Bhalke, so try to provide a fiddle which reproduce your issue.

Comment: Your code working as expected: http://www.bootply.com/1YF9CVY0zK

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's not closing reliably when clicking outside. It sometimes response to escape, but double clicking outside it in the gray area often selects the text in the modal. Inspection of the element does not show any kind of overflow (it's a small message), so it just doesn't work right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have written custom code to solve this.

```
   $("body").on("click", ".modal-dialog", function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('modal-dialog')) {
            var hidePopup = $(e.target.parentElement).attr('id');
            $('#' + hidePopup).modal('hide');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `data-backdrop="static"` and `data-keyboard="false"` attributes to that modal (ie where you have `class='modal'`)

`data-backdrop="true"` is the default behaviour that allows for background click dismissal and `data-backdrop="static"` is the behaviour that your explaining, no dismissal, so probably you have set it somewhere to "static".

`data-keyboard="false"` is for not allowing ESC

Answer (score 2):

You can pass options to the modal as :

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    show:true,
    backdrop:true,
    keyboard:true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove modal class from modal start div and

$('#MyModal').modal({ backdrop: false });
$('body').removeClass("modal-open");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 It should work if you are using bootstrap 3 

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="modalExample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Small Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and call it as call it as : $('#modalExample').modal();